# How can I use Xpath in Event Viewer to filter on substrings of the values of attributes?

Tags: xml, event-viewer

I am trying to define Windows Eventviewer views using Xpath xml queries. I am able to select on attributes if I match on the entire value; for example

```
[EventData[Data[@Name="Image"] and (Data="C:\windows\system32\calc.exe")]]
```

I am not able to search for items where I do not know, for example, the full path.  The example which doesn't work is

```
[EventData[Data[@Name="Image"] and (Data="*firefox.exe")]]"
```

Supposedly there is a "contains" function in Xpath but it isn't supported in the xpath implemented in EventViewer.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Event Log supports a subset of XPath 1.0 and only contains only 3 functions: position, band and timediff.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd996910(v=vs.85).aspx#limitations